# Python getopt() in __main__

Tags: python, getopt

I'm a Python beginner and have successfully gotten my first program with CLI parameters passed in to run.  Got lots of help from this [Handling command line options](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html).

My question is: Why in Example 5.45 a separate `def main(argv)` has been used, instead of calling the `try/except` block within `__main__`  itself.

#### Example 5.45

```
def main(argv):                         
    grammar = "kant.xml"
    try:                                
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hg:d", ["help", "grammar="]) 2
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)                     

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Hope someone versed in Python could share your wisdom.

TIA - 
Ashant

Comment: [This][1] thread has explained this issue in brief details. Hope this help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict technical reason, but it is quite idiomatic to keep the code outside functions as short as possible. Specifically, putting the code into the module scope would turn the variables `grammar`, `opts` and `args` into global public variables, even though they are only required inside the main code. Furthermore, using a dedicated `main` function simplifies unit-testing this function.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of using a `main` function is that it allows for easy code re-use:

```
import sys
import script

script.main(sys.argv[1:])
# or, e.g. script.main(['-v', 'file.txt']), etc
```

Any code in the script's `__main__` block won't be run if it is imported as a module. So the `main` function acts as a simple interface providing access to all the normal functionality of the script. The `__main__` block will then usually contain just a single call to `main`, plus any other non-essential code (such as tests).

Some tips from the author of Python on how to write a good `main` function can be found [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829).